# In python, if the user enters a string instead of number (integer value) then how can we show message to user that input is invalid?

Tags: python

```
var=int(input("Enter anything ==>"))
if(var%2==0): 
    print(var," is a Even number")
elif((var>="a" and var<="z") or (var>="A" and var<="Z")):
    print(var," is String")
    print("Enter a number to find it is even or odd")
else:
    print(var," is a Odd number")
```

**OUTPUT**

> C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\All Desktop
> apps\Python>python input.py
>  Enter an enter code everything ==>6
>  6  is a Even
> number

> C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\All Desktop apps\Python>python
> input.py
>  Enter anything ==>sdsd
>  Traceback (most recent call
> last):
>    File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\All Desktop
> apps\Python\input.py", line 5, in 
> var=int(input("Enter anything ==>"))
>  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sdsd'

#### > #if the user enters anything like any alphabet or special character, then how can we show msg to the user that the input is invalid or its
> an alphabet or a special character or an integer or about specific
> data type



==> var=int(input("Enter anything ==>")) 
==> #var=input("Enter anything ==>")

---

---

## Incorrect Code -->

[image]

---

## Incorrect Output -->

[image]

---

## Correct code using exception handling-->

[image]

---

## Correct output-->

[image]

---

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) instead of an image. Please also _ask a specific question_! What's wrong with your code? Does it exit without doing anything? Does it do the wrong thing? Have you done any [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? Please read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is `try/except`:

```
var = input("Enter anything ==>")
try:
    if int(var) % 2:  
        print(f"{var} is an odd number")
    else:
        print(f"{var} is an even number")
except ValueError:
    print(f"{var} is not a number")
```

If you want to re-prompt the user when they enter something that's not a number, put the whole thing in a `while` loop and `break` it when they enter a valid number.

```
while True:
    var = input("Enter anything ==>")
    try:
        if int(var) % 2:  
            print(f"{var} is an odd number")
        else:
            print(f"{var} is an even number")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print(f"{var} is not a number")
```